Speed up string assignments to list in Cython
I used re to group a long string, and put the obtained substrings into a list based on conditions specified by a dict to output. I found a significant improvement on the speed using Cython comparing to Python, but would expect a further improvement.
A simple code in temp_test.pyx is:
cimport cython

import re


@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
def cleave(str long_str, str rules, dict term_char):
    """
    Cleaves a long string into substrings.

    """
    cdef:
        object compiler = re.compile(rules)
        Py_ssize_t i, ns
        Py_ssize_t nk = 0
        Py_ssize_t nq = <ssize_t> len(long_str)
        int p, t
        list split_str = compiler.split(long_str)
        list substrs = nq * [None]
        str s

    ns = <ssize_t> len(split_str)
    for i in range(ns):
        if split_str[i] is not None:
            s = split_str[i]
            p = len(s)
            if p == 1 and s in term_char:
                t = term_char[s]
                if t == 0:
                    substrs[nk] = split_str[i - 1]
                else:
                    substrs[nk] = split_str[i] + split_str[i + 1]
                nk += 1

    return substrs[:nk]

with the test code:
from temp_test import cleave
from typing import Dict

def test_cleave():
    long_str: str = r"ABCEDFRFR"

    rules: str = r"([BD])"
    term_char: Dict[str, int] = {"B": 0, "D": 1}

    subs = cleave(long_str, rules, term_char)
    print(subs)

After using cython -a to annotate the temp_test.pyx, I found nearly all lines were highlighted. Since the cleave will be called large number of times, and there exist lots of assignments of strings from a list (i.e., split_str ) to another list (i.e., substrs) in the function, I found there always exist checks like:
if (unlikely(__pyx_v_split_str == Py_None)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "object of type 'NoneType' has no len()");
    __PYX_ERR(0, 24, __pyx_L1_error)
  }
  __pyx_t_5 = __Pyx_PyList_GET_SIZE(__pyx_v_split_str); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_5 == ((Py_ssize_t)-1))) __PYX_ERR(0, 24, __pyx_L1_error)
  __pyx_v_ns = ((Py_ssize_t)__pyx_t_5);


I think disable those checks can improve the performance. How to achieve this?
I found that @cython.wraparound(False) was highlighted too with lots of checks (too long not show here), is this because I check the key in dict? I.e., s in term_char. Do we have a better alternative?

I'm very often use memoryview, malloc, calloc etc. for numeric operations and calculations, but not familiar with string operations using cython, any suggestions are very appreciated.

Do you want to use Cython, or do you just want a fast solution for the task and believe Cython is the best way? There might be a fast Python solution, too...

wraparound(False) - this will probably just be mislabeling the code that creates the function. It has nothing to do with keys in dicts and the decorator itself has no cost.

@nocomment If there exist fast Python solutions, would be great then, as the string operations and list in Python have been optimised and are better than Cython (from others' experiments online). But from my experiments, this Cython implementation is much faster. So the further optimisation, from my perspective, would be based on Cython.

How much faster? (And for alternative solutions, the task would have to be clarified... What it is in general, what your real strings and dicts are like... Could be done in a separate question, this one for your technical questions about Cython and another about the task.)

@nocomment >3 times faster. term_char is as it is here, but the string input is much longer (thousands to tens of thousands), a bit more pattern for re.compile so that more checks (i.e., s in term_char) are performed, and I may combine more substrings.

There's a few small things I can see which are likely making it worse:
if p == 1 and s in term_char:
    t = term_char[s]

There you're effective looking up term_char[s] twice. Maybe:
if p == 1:
    t = term_char.get(s, None)
    if t is None:
         continue

or something like that.

int p, t

Typing t is probably a pessimization. Essentially the only thing you do with t is to get it out of a dict and compare it with 0.
If you just left t untyped the getting it out of a dict is free (a tiny bit of ref-counting) and comparing it with 0 is almost certainly pretty cheap (since all Python int(0) are usually the same integer).
Typing it as int means you get a Python object out of a dict, then do a type-check and extract the integer value. The comparison with 0 might be slightly quicker, but overall it's likely slower.
(Typing p is probably fine).

In contrast, what might be worthwhile is to rewrite
substrs[nk] = split_str[i] + split_str[i + 1]

as
substrs[nk] = s + <str>(split_str[i + 1])

(i.e. let it know both components are strings). This'll let it go down a slightly accelerated string concatenation route, rather than generic addition.

if (unlikely(__pyx_v_split_str == Py_None)) {

can be eliminated with @cython.nonecheck(False). Obviously you need to satisfy yourself that that's appropriate.

I suspect all of the above will be marginal improvements though, and you shouldn't expect any big improvements from this kind of optimization.

Thanks. Yes, the improvement is marginal, but it is still very helpful. But @cython.nonecheck(False) does not really remove the unlikely(__pyx_v_split_str == Py_None) check.

The next thing to do would probably be to profile it. Either in Cython (with line_profile), or in C. Or possibly with a Python profiler on something close to the Cython code but in Python. My guess would be that the dict lookup is what you should try to eliminate. But that is a guess and you should measure it first.
